# Flutter Scrollbar prevent Scrollbar showing up on horizontal listview

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a `Scrollbar` on top of my widget tree showing on the right side when scrolling vertically. Now further on in my widget tree I have a horizontal `ListView`. The scrollbar is showing up there too if the user scrolls on horizontal. I don't want the `ScrollBar` showing up there. Is there any common way to disable showing up on the horizontal axis?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scrollbar(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 5,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(25),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                   ...
```

Later on the listview:

```
      Expanded(child:
            Consumer<Model>(builder: (context, myModel, child) {
          return ListView.builder(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemCount: list.length,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: list[index],
              child: GestureDetector(
```

Comment: does anybody have an idea? this should be a common issue which can be solved somehow :/

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a widget that contains two ListViews:

```
Scrollbar(
    controller: scrollController,
    child: ListView.builder(
      controller: scrollController,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return SizedBox(
          height: 90,
          child: ListView.separated(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.blue,
              );
            },
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              );
            },
            itemCount: 50,
          ),
        );
      },
      itemCount: 50,
    ),
  ),
```

A simple solution would be to wrap the ListView with a **NotificationListener** and set the **onNotification** to return true. In this case, the horizontal ListView would be the widget in question. This will tell the NotificationListener that the notification has been handled, which will stop it from sending out a ScrollNotification up the Widget Tree.

So the **solution** would be:

```
 Scrollbar(
    controller: scrollController,
    child: ListView.builder(
      controller: scrollController,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return SizedBox(
          height: 90,
          child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
            onNotification: (_) => true,
            child: ListView.separated(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: themeColor,
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                );
              },
              itemCount: 50,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      itemCount: 50,
    ),
  ),
```

For an *in-depth understanding*, consider reading up the  [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NotificationListener-class.html)